# timeout for large input in biginteger

Tags: java, biginteger

Consider a permutation of numbers 1 to n written on a paper. Let’s denote the product of its element as p and the sum of its elements as s. Given a positive integer n, your task is to determine whether p is divisible by s or not.

i tried by using bigInteger concept but out of 50 test case 30 is successfully passed but rest of them are showing timeout which may be because of recursion.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class TestClass {
    static BigInteger factorial(int n){

        if(n==0||n==1)
            return new BigInteger("1");

        return BigInteger.valueOf(n).multiply(factorial(n-1));
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int nn=n*(n+1)/2;
        BigInteger sum=BigInteger.valueOf(nn);
        BigInteger p=factorial(n);    

        if((p.mod(sum)).equals(BigInteger.valueOf(0)))
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
   }
}
```

for the sample test case is like 
input is 3 and its output should be "YES".since (1+2+3) divides (1*2*3).

Comment: You might not have to calculate the entire product. After each multiplication, check whether the intermediate product is divisible by the sum; if it is, you can stop, as the final product will also be divisible. This will not help with "negative" cases, but might speed up the "positive" ones considerably.

Comment: BTW, what is really meant by "it's elements"? Are you sure that that's "all the numbers from 1 to n"?

Comment: @tobias_k yeah you are right

Comment: Also, you might get an integer overflow while calculating `nn`, better use `long` or also ´BigInteger`. What is the upper-bound for `n`, anyway?

Comment: FWIW, not really relevant to the question, but consider using BigInteger.ZERO and BigInteger.ONE for the obvious values. No need to call `valueOf()` for these.

Comment: 1. There is no permutation here. 2. Java has no concept of "timeout", so nobody knows what you're referring to. 3. **Which cases** are not succeeding?

Comment: @JamesKPolk  https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/march-circuits-19/algorithm/does-it-divide-3c60b8fb/

Comment: just go through this link.

Comment: But that requires a login. I won't sign up just to be able to judge this question for you. Please add the relevant details to your question, and do not tell people to click links, especially not links where they must sign up to access the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the recursion and use the for loop to calculate the factorial.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class TestClass {
static void factorial(long n, long nn){

    BigInteger answer=new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger sum=BigInteger.valueOf(nn);
    int foundMatch =0;
    for(long i=n;i>0;i--){
        answer=answer.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i)));
        if((answer.mod(sum)).equals(BigInteger.valueOf(0)))
        {
            System.out.println("YES");
            foundMatch = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(foundMatch!=1)
    System.out.println("NO");
}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    long n=s.nextLong();
    long nn=n*(n+1)/2;

    factorial(n, nn);    
}

}
```

Comment: Sir, I tried What you told but now it was passing 3 test cases only out of 50.

Comment: Do you have to user recursion only ??

Comment: Converting a `long` to `BigInteger` long after it has overflows (probably multiple times) does not really help. Use `BigInteger` from the beginning.

Comment: Sir, Any method was fine for me . But it was not getting for your answer and even my logic also.

Comment: shall i take input in form of biginteger

Comment: I found bit more details on this, check here..  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90911/calculating-the-factorial-of-a-number-efficiently

Comment: @VinodSinghBist ,Sir your code was getting time out for 15 testcases

Comment: Lets improve this then :) , edited code .check this one

Comment: No sir, Still it was getting time out.

Comment: Ok, change the for loop to go heigh to low, for(long i=n;i>0;i--) . . updated code, check now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190614/discussion-between-vinod-singh-bist-and-satyanarayanareddy-tadi).

Comment: Do you really need the full factorial? You only need to know if  twice the factorial can be divided by n and n+1 (because nn = n*(n+1)/2). The factorial can always be divided by n, as n is part of the factorial. So you need toconcentrate on n+1 only. 2*factorial must be divisible by n+1. That could be simpler and faster than the full calculation. No time to work it out; just a quick reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic that if the intermediate product of the factorial is divisible by the sum, then the entire factorial is also divisible by sum.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {
static boolean isFactorialDivisible(int n, BigInteger sum) {
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        p = p.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
        if (p.mod(sum).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
             return true;
        }
        BigInteger gcd = p.gcd(sum);
        if (!gcd.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            p = p.divide(gcd);
            sum = sum.divide(gcd);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int nn = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(nn);
    boolean p = isFactorialDivisible(n, sum);
    if (p)
    System.out.println("YES");
    else
    System.out.println("NO");
}
}
```

Comment: Sir, Still time out is coming

Comment: No sir, still it was getting time out for 15 test cases

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static int prime(int n)
    {
        int count=0,flag=0;
        if(n==1)
        flag=1;
        if(n==2)
        flag=0;
        else {
        for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++) {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }}
        if(flag==1)
        return 1;
        return 0;

    }
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=s.nextInt();
        while(t-->0)
        {
            int flag=0;
            int n=s.nextInt();
            if(n%2==0)
            {
             flag=prime(n+1);   
            }
            else
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        if(flag==1)
        System.out.println("YES");
        else
        System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```